# python:two programs to delete val from nums

Tags: python

write a python program to delete val from array:
the first program is:

```
class Solution(object):
    def removeElement(self,nums,val):

        for x in nums:
            if x == val:
                nums.remove(val)
        return len(nums)
```

when the nums is [3,3], the val is 3, the output is :1

the second program is :

```
class Solution(object):
    def removeElement(self,nums,val):

        while val in nums:
            nums.remove(val)
        return len(nums)
```

the nums is [3,3],the val is 3,the output is :0

could you please tell me the difference and reason

Comment: Looping through an array while removing elements from it usually causes weird behaviour and problems.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a hard time iterating through something that is being changed during the iteration. It might fail or return unexpected results or never exit the iteration.

> Because a container doesn't even keep track of iterators that are out
>   on it, much less hook even altering-method to loop over every such
>   iterator and somehow magically let each iterator know about the
>   alterations. It would be a lot subtle, complex code, and checks
>   slowing down very frequent operations.

```
nums=[3,4]
val=3

for x in nums:
    print(x,nums)
    if x > val:
        nums.append(4)
```

The above code will not exit the iteration.So the correct way is to use a list comprehension to create a new list containing only the elements you don't want to remove:

```
print([i for i in nums if i!=val])
```

Or in-place alteration:

```
nums[:] = [i for i in nums if i!=val]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you are deleting an element inside the list while iterating over the elements of the list. That's a problem because you will run out of iterations after the first `remove`.

If the list is, for example, `l = [1, 1, 2, 2]` and you call `removeElement(l, 2)` after the first `2` is deleted, the length of `l` will be 3 and there won't be any iterations left (the list will be `[1, 1, 2]` and you will be at iteration number 3, that's why the loop stops and you get returned `[1, 1, 2]`).

In the second case, the `while` statement is: while there is still a 2 in the list, continue removing 2 from the list. This way, after the first iteration the `l` will look like `[1, 1, 2]` and there would still be a 2 inside it, so the loop continues and you get `[1, 1]`.

You can apply this example on your case with `l = [3, 3]` and see if you understand it.

Hope that helped :)