# Remove Element in array. I don't understand how work output in my case [python]

Tags: python

I don't understand how work **output** in my case. Could you explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

**[task](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-element/description/):**(27. Remove Element)

> Given an integer array `nums` and an integer `val`, remove all occurrences of `val` in `nums` **[in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm)**. The order of the elements may be changed. Then return *the number of elements in* `nums` *which are not equal to* `val`.
>
> Consider the number of elements in `nums` which are not equal to `val` be `k`, to get accepted, you need to do the following things:
>
> - Change the array `nums` such that the first `k` elements of `nums` contain the elements which are not equal to `val`. The remaining elements of `nums` are not important as well as the size of `nums`.
> - Return `k`.

**My solution:**

```
class Solution:
    def removeElement(self, nums: List[int], val: int) -> int:
        if len(nums) > 1:
            
            nums = [u for u in nums if u != val]
            print("nums = ", nums)

            if val not in nums:
                return len(nums)
```

**Testcase:**

nums =[0,1,2,2,3,0,4,2]

val = 2

**Results:**

Stdout (print in loop): nums = [0, 1, 3, 0, 4]

Output: [0,1,**2,2**,3]

Expected: [0,1,4,0,3]

Comment: So your problem is that after removing the val in the list-comprehension, you still get this output: `[0,1,2,2,3]`?

Comment: Helpful related info: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not removing the elements in-place, so `nums` outside the function is not affected.

One option is to iterate over the list and remove items with `pop`. To avoid index out of range exception iterate over the list from end to start

```
for i in range(len(nums) - 1, 0, -1):
    if nums[i] == val:
        nums.pop(i)
```

Comment: with some changes it is work, thanks
`for i in range(len(nums) - 1, -1, -1)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do in-place list comprehension. If so you are missing: `[:]` at the end of nums. I suggest you take a look at the similar qustion: [python:two programs to delete val from nums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312917/pythontwo-programs-to-delete-val-from-nums)

Answer (score 0):

You must remove val occurrences in nums List **in-place**.
but you are assigning another list to nums variable by writing this line

```
nums = [u for u in nums if u != val]
```

you can do this

```
try:
    while True:
        nums.remove(val)
except ValueError:
    pass
```